# Invitation letter for Romanian tourist visa

Tags: visas, invitation-letters

I am an Indian citizen with US Permanent Residency.

I am planning to visit Romania soon just for spending a vacation, however I came to know that Indian citizens need an invitation letter for Romanian tourist visa.

I heard in some places that it is not a strict requirement.
Also I came to know that persons who belong to the countries that need the invitation letter, if they are permanent residents of Canada, the requirement is waived.

I do not need a travel agency for the tour, I was planning to do it alone. Could anyone comment on:

i. Is it absolutely necessary to have the invitation letter?

ii. Is the requirement waived for a US permanent resident?

iii. Is it possible to get a travel package for one day from a travel agency and get an invitation letter?

I am going for 7 days, that way I don't have to have buy package for all 7 days.

Thank you very much in advance!

Argha

Answer (score 1):

The invitation exemption applies not only to permanent residents in Canada, but to those other countries, including the United States:

> **Getting a visa on the basis of an invitation approved by the [General Inspectorate for Immigration – Romanian Ministry of Internal Affairs](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2051#null)**
>
> *Moreover, short-stay visas can be granted with the exemption from the IGI-MAI invitation procedure to the following categories of third-country nationals*
>
> -- nationals who hold a valid residence permit in states whose citizens are not required an entry visa to the Member States of the European Union or the European Economic Area, or to the Schengen Area Member States;

Comment: Thanks Giorgio. The embassy confirmed the same as well.

Comment: @ArghaB excellent; you can 'accept' the answer by selecting the tick mark.